# MongoDB enumerates all the data types of a key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have the following collection,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cfa3281614216570a718539"),
    "vendor_id": '11111'
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cfa3281614216570a718539"),
    "vendor_id": '11112'
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cfa3281614216570a718539"),
    "vendor_id": 10000
}
```

I like to find out all the data types of `vendor_id`;

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
    [ 
        { "$project": { "fieldType": {  "$type": "$vendor_id"  } } } 
    ]
)
```

but I am wondering if there is a way to just list all the data types of `vendor_id`, something like;

```
["string", "int"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "verdorIds": {
      "$addToSet": {
        "$type": "$vendor_id"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```